# xmlhttp.readyState not working with mysql transaction

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, readystate

i have an ajax function where i am simply calling a php page which has a mysql transaction to be run. On checking mysql log, i have verified that the transaction runs successfully but xmlhttp object jumps to the else statement readyState and status.

my js code:

```
function promoteOptionsAllot(stid,cid,nsid,elid,flag){
anchor = document.getElementById('promoteAnchor'+elid);
imgContainer = document.getElementById('promoteStatus'+elid);
if(flag == 1){
opt1 = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('promote_option1').value);
opt2 = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('promote_option2').value);
opt3 = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('promote_option3').value);
opt4 = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('promote_option4').value);
params =   "stid="+encodeURIComponent(stid)+"&course="+encodeURIComponent(cid)+"&sem="+encodeURIComponent(nsid)+"&element="+encodeURIComponent(elid)+"&popt1="+opt1+"&popt2="+opt2+"&popt3="+opt3+" &popt4="+opt4+"&flag="+encodeURIComponent(flag);
 }
else if(flag == 2){
params =   "stid="+encodeURIComponent(stid)+"&course="+encodeURIComponent(cid)+"&sem="+encodeURIComponent(nsid)+"&element="+encodeURIComponent(elid)+"&flag="+encodeURIComponent(flag);
}


if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 { 
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
 {
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  { 
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('prBox'));
document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('prBackground'));
result = xmlhttp.responseText;  
if(result == "done"){
anchor.innerHTML = "<span style='color:#198D19;'><b>Promoted</b></span>";
imgContainer.src = "tick.png";
}else {
alert("There was a problem serving the request. Please try again.");
imgContainer.src = "cross.jpg";
}
 }
else{
imgContainer.src = "alert.gif";
}
 }
xmlhttp.open("POST","promoptallot.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(params);
}
```

Its an onclick event of a link and in clicking the link although the transaction is successful but somehow the imagecontainer shows alert.gif which means it never runs the code inside the readystate == 4 and status == 200 statement.

Please don't suggest using jquery. I know its a stable framework and other things but i need an answer using this only.

Comment: Are you echoing "done" in your PHP script after the transaction? `if (result == "done")` I would try a `console.log(result)` to see what your PHP script is outputing. It might be outputting more than the exact string "done"

Comment: @crush yes i am echoing done after the transaction completes

Comment: Okay, I reread your question, and I see that you say "it never runs the code inside the readystate == 4 and status == 200 statement."

Comment: @crush so what do u think now is happening?

Comment: Are you processing multiple AJAX queries with the same xmlhttp object? Where do you declare xmlhttp at? Also, I think you should output `xmlhttp.status` and `xmlhttp.readyState` before that if block so you can see what their values are.

Comment: this is the only function that i am calling on the onclick event and these are the only ajax queries that i am firing.

Comment: yes i did try to output the xmlhttp.readyState and when the status was  2 it had already fired the queries which i confirmed through mysql log and the status of the image changed immediately to the error image. it remained that even after the status outputted to 4.

Comment: You mean when the readyState was equal to 4? What was the value of `xmlhttp.status` though? If it's never 200, then your code will never fire, even if `readyState == 4`

Comment: it was always 200. i have answered the problem i found, please check. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the console, i found the problem at line `document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('prBox'));
document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('prBackground'));`

These lines had to be executed on a case basis and i didn't put it inside the if statement.

now after putting it like `if (flag ==1){ document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('prBox'));
document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('prBackground'));
}` it works as intended.

Thanks.